# Send and receive data in c# network programming winform

Tags: c#, winforms, network-programming

I have a small server that is received and sends the message back to the client. 
    this is the client-side
    when I open the client it will connect to server through Connect()

```
public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Connect();
                CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            }
```

this is my connect

```
void Connect()
            {
                ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9999);
                server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                try
                {
                    server.Connect(ipep);
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(e));           
                }
                Thread listen = new Thread(Receive);
                listen.IsBackground = true; ;
                listen.Start();
            }
```

and I have a receive like this

```
void Receive()
            {
                datarec = new byte[1024];
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        string StringData;
                        rec = server.Receive(datarec);
                        StringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, rec);
                        txtShow.Text = StringData;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Close();
                }
            }
```

and I send data through a button have Send method

```
void Send(string s)
            {
                data = new byte[1024];
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
                server.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None); 
            }
```

Send button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string s = txtText.Text;
                Send(s);          
            }
```

this is the server-side
    I have a thread server

```
public static void Process(Socket client)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                int recv;
                string dataInput;
                IPEndPoint clientep = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
                Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}", clientep.Address, clientep.Port);             

                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {                   
                         recv = client.Receive(data);
                        dataInput = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                        Console.WriteLine(dataInput);
                        client.Send(data);
                    }
                    catch (SocketException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }
```

}
                }
this is the server main
    public static void Main() 
            {

```
            byte[] rec = new byte[1024];
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9999);
            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            server.Bind(ipep);
            server.Listen(10);

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client...");
            Console.WriteLine("LOG CHAT");
            while (true)
            {
                Socket client = server.Accept();
                Core core = new Core();
                Thread t = new Thread(() => Core.Process(client));
                t.Start();
            }
        }
```

the server receive message but when it sends a message back it has an error "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"
    Can you guys tell me where I was wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `client.Send(data)` in your server code, you will send the whole 1024 byte buffer back to the client, not just the data received. 
Encoding.ASCII.GetString in the client could fail when processing this garbage and the exception will close the connection.

Try to replace `client.Send(data)` by `client.Send(data, recv, SocketFlags.None)`.

Also, you should not update UI controls directly from a background thread, Use [Control.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke) for this. Failing to do so will also throw an exception and close the connection.